# java main method not found when i try to run from console while the same code works from IDE

Tags: java, methods

I have two .java files in the same folder C:\System  One has all the functions defined and the other is the tester class with the main function which instantiates an object of the other class and tests its methods.

I am able to compile both files but not run the main file, getting the error that main method not found

I am new and really struggling, any help is greatly appreciated.

What should be my Classpath and  from which folder should I run the program and with what command. Also do I need to include a package System; at beginning of each class file.

Really appreciate the help!

Comment: Trying going to the `C:\System` dir, verify your .class files are there (2) and run `java -cp . <main class name>`

Comment: Share your code please.